# Why a huge amount of old questions of this site migrated from Super User?

Tags: discussion, migration, broken-windows

Why is there a huge amount of old questions migrated from Super User? Is there any interesting story behind it?

Searching on questions sorted by "newest", and going to the last page of results (oldest questions) I found at least 30-40 consecutive (according to time) questions migrated from the Super User.

Examples:

- [What is Wolfram Alpha good for?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/what-is-wolfram-alpha-good-for)
- [How can I get code syntax highlighting in Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/how-can-i-get-code-syntax-highlighting-in-google-docs)
- [Google Maps: Do calculated distances include uphills?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21286/google-maps-do-calculated-distances-include-uphills)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* anyway, that it is a natural result of this site being opened.

Consider:

- Web Apps was the first site opened via [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)
- Before that, there had been a number of (off-topic) web app related questions on Super User<sup>1</sup>
- Web Apps has been a migration target from Super User from the beginning

What's probably happened is that there was a lot of pent-up demand and, once this site opened, Super User finally had a place to send decent but off-topic questions.

After seeing a couple of your examples, it's clear. Those questions pre-date the creation of Web Apps. So...

1. Web Apps opens
2. People go to Super User to find questions for Web Apps and ask for them to be migrated. (There didn't used to be age limit on migrations.)

Since the meta data of a question, like the date/time it was created, don't change in a migration, if you sort strictly by age many of those questions will be from before Web Apps existed to accept questions of its own. (The private beta of Web Apps began June 30, 2010. By definition any question with a date before that will have been migrated from elsewhere.) The same will be true of many of the early Area 51 sites. (Lately, however, the policy has been *not* to migrate questions to sites that are in beta, so you won't see it as much or at all at other Stack Exchange sites.)

---

<sup>1</sup> A considerable motivation for creating Web Apps.

Answer (score 0):

## Complement to ale's answer

The first site was Stack Overflow, created in 2008. In 2009 were created Server Fault for system adminsitrators and Super User for computer power users. The last use was promoted as "anything goes there". Other sites were created known as Stack Exchange 1.0. Later was decided create a site to manage site proposals which was called Area 51. Sites derived from this process were called Stack Exchange 2.0. The first one was Web Applications.

Apparently most of the poeple participating in the Web Applications proposals were Super User users. Somehow many old questions from Super User were migrated but later to other sites but later the migration policy was changed.

Many of the questions that were migrated looks to be "broken windows":

> innapropiate questions to justify posting similar questions.

The "broken windows" might still be open because there is not in place a exhaustive review process. They are revised case by case as the questions are bumped due to being edited, a new answer be posted or were brought to mod attention directly, i.e. by a flag or indirectly, i.e. by link in or search results.

## Related Meta Stack Exchange Posts

- [Should we migrate old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8004/289691)

  - Created 2009
  - Accepted answer from 2012 points to [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)
- [Should we migrate old questions to new SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76702/289691) from 2011
- [How to migrate old questions to a new graduated site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152597/289691) from 2012